# MySql query ordering in JOIN tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Good day every one
I have three MySql tables

-Doc

-DocType

-Org

I made a query like that:

> **Select** Doc.Code,Doc.DataAccept,DocTypes.Name,Org.Name
>
> **From**
>   Doc,DocTypes,Org
>
> **Where** Doc.Type=DocTypes.Code **AND** Doc.Org=Org.Code **AND** Doc.Code;

in Result i have

> |Code|DataAccept|Name|Name|
>
> ```
> 17  |    -   |  - |  - | 
>
> 18  |    -   |  - |  - | 
>
> 24  |    -   |  - |  - | 
>
> 26  |    -   |  - |  - | 
>
> 32  |    -   |  - |  - |
> ```

the Code field is not in series

if made query like

> **Select** Doc.Code,Doc.DataAccept,DocTypes.Name,Org.Name
>
> **From**
>   Doc,DocTypes,Org
>
> **Where** Doc.Type=DocTypes.Code **AND** Doc.Org=Org.Code **AND** Doc.Code **AND** Doc.Code < 100;

than it's ok

> |Code|DataAccept|Name|Name|
>
> ```
> 1   |    -   |  - |  - | 
>
> 2   |    -   |  - |  - | 
>
> 3   |    -   |  - |  - | 
>
> 4   |    -   |  - |  - | 
>
> 5   |    -   |  - |  - |
> ```

if Doc.Code < 1000 than again it's not in series
I try to use ORDER BY Code

> **Select** Doc.Code,Doc.DataAccept,DocTypes.Name,Org.Name
>
> **From**
>   Doc,DocTypes,Org
>
> **Where** Doc.Type=DocTypes.Code **AND** Doc.Org=Org.Code **AND** Doc.Code **AND** Doc.Code
>
> **ORDER BY** Code **DESC**;

and

> **Select** Doc.Code,Doc.DataAccept,DocTypes.Name,Org.Name
>
> **From**
>   Doc,DocTypes,Org
>
> **Where** Doc.Type=DocTypes.Code **AND** Doc.Org=Org.Code **AND** Doc.Code **AND** Doc.Code
>
> **ORDER BY** Code **ASC**;

but in result i have ordered not in series

What i did missing here ?

Thank you for your time , and forgive my English

> "-" - it is a normal data , use it just for represent.

Comment: You can NEVER trust the ordering of a select without an `ORDER BY`. Is `ORDER BY Code` not working? Give us an example of the ordering WITH `ORDER BY Code`.

Comment: I see you also have a `DocTypes.Code` besides `Doc.Code`. So could you try `ORDER BY Doc.Code`. (Or like @artmees sugests `ORDER BY 1`)

Comment: yes,thank you for reply order by 1 is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Doc.Code,Doc.DataAccept,DocTypes.Name,Org.Name

FROM Doc LEFT OUTER JOIN DocTypes JOIN Org

ON Doc.Type=DocTypes.Code AND Doc.Org=Org.Code;

WHERE Doc.Code < 1000 ;

ORDER BY 1
```

this [explanation](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) might be useful as well.

Comment: Working solution for me was adding order by 1 to my query
Thank you 
and thanks for explanation link

Comment: Seems that my problem was that i have DocTypes.Code and Doc.Code as Rik was say. So the ORDER BY Doc.Code works fine to.